# How can I re-initialize Superfish everytime the page post back?

Tags: asp.net, jquery-plugins, superfish

I just found out about superfish and currently using it on an asp.net. The problem is every time the page post back superfish plugin disappear. The site needs to run on IE6 so the javascript part is very important I was thinking of creating a javascript function that contains tha initialization of the plugin and called it at the page Page Load event from codebehind.

Can that be done or is there better way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using superfish's menu on my site. I have a custom web control which emits my markup for me.

Then I use $(document).ready() to initlize superfish in. This will be called every time the page loads even on post back.

I assume when you say the menu dissapears that the menu is still there just its being rendered as a plain list?

Comment: Yes the menu is still there but the it is just a plain list. It is ok with other browers but IE6 doesn't have the hover thing so it loses the ability to function after postback.

Comment: Do you have a URL I can hit? I support IE6 on my site and haven't had any problems.